# Replace first and last occurrences of a json string

Tags: android, json, string, replace

I am fetching the response from webservice and trying to parse the json string.

The response string is,

```
  [{"TbbId":0,"PropertyID":1066637,"BuilderID":"9250c666-e76c-4206-8b37-343b2bb11a89","BuilderName":"David Weekley Homes","Notes":"","Address":"1 TBB4519","SchoolDistrict":null,"School":null,"CityID":"Fort Mill","CountyID":"","StateID":"SC","Zip":"29708","Lat":"35.037240000000000","Lng":"-80.979742000000000","Price":364990,"PropertyStatusID":"AV","PropertyStatusDescription":"Available","StageID":"TBB","StageDescription":"To-Be-Built Home","TypeID":1,"TypeDescription":"House","SubdivisionID":4121,"SubdivisionName":"Baxter Village","FloorPlanNumber":"4519","Remarks":"","OldNew":null,"PropertyInMyListFlag":null,"FreePostingFlag":"F","PropertySubscriptionPlan":null,"PropertySubscriptionPaymentType":null,"BalanceAmount":0,"PropertyLicenseFlag":"N","PlanNumber":null,"SubdivisionFloorPlanID":null,"SubdivisionFloorPlanName":"Ridgegate","ShowDirections":"Mon-Sat 9:30am-5:30pm; Sun 12:30pm-5:30","DrivingDirections":"Take I-77, Exit 85 - Fort Mill / Highway 160. Take Highway 160 West. Proceed past the Main Baxter Village Entrance. Turn Left into Baxter Village at the next entrance marked by a white fence and stone monument which is Front Street. Take your first right onto Richards Crossing, the David Weekley Model is located on the left at 3439 Richards Crossi","PropertyClass":"TBB","RemarksId":0,"VerifiedBU":"Y","SubdivisionDescription":null,"Contact1Name":"Traci Belk","Contact1Phone":"800-393-9968","Contact1PhoneAlt":"","Contact2Name":"","Contact2Phone":"","Contact2PhoneAlt":"","Email":"homes@dwhomes.com","Beds":4,"Baths":2,"HalfBaths":1,"Living":0,"Dining":0,"OtherRooms":"","Stories":2.0,"Master":"Down","Garage":2.0,"SquareFeet":2474,"LotSize":"","LotDescription":"David Weekley homes Traditional Collection in Baxter Village offers floor plans featuring innovative design and unsurpassed quality. This charming community combines work, play and living, all within the Village. In Baxter Village, you&rsquo;ll enjoy:&nbsp; Parks, playgrounds and sports courts Swimming pool and clubhouse Community library and two community centers Full time activities director for events Baxter Town Center with shopping and dining Final Phase of Baxter Village Nearly Sold Out! Love Baxter Village but want to build a more customized home on a larger estate lot? We can help! Learn more about our Build on Your Lot program.","CommunityTypeID":11,"CommunityTypeDescription":"Standard","LotWidth":0,"LotLength":0,"Acres":0,"Water":"","Sewer":"","DryUtilities":"","Topography":"","Trees":"","VirtualTourURL":"","InternetOption":"","WaterId":0,"SewerId":0,"DryUtilitiesId":0,"TopographyId":0,"TreesId":0,"InternetOptionId":0,"WaterIds":null,"SewerIds":null,"DryUtilitiesIds":null,"TopographyIds":null,"TreesIds":null,"InternetOptionIds":null,"MinimumPrice":0,"MaximumPrice":0,"MinimumPropertySquareFeet":0,"MaximumPropertySquareFeet":0,"MinimumBeds":0,"MaximumBeds":0,"MinimumBaths":0,"MaximumBaths":0,"MinimumHalfBaths":0,"MaximumHalfBaths":0,"MinimumStories":0,"MaximumStories":0,"MinimumGarages":0,"MaximumGarages":0,"IsModel":null,"CustomHomeModelId":0,"BrandName":null,"SchoolDistrictID":0,"SchoolDistrictName":null,"ElementarySchool":null,"MiddleSchool":null,"HighSchool":null,"SchoolComments":"Please visit the school district's website for additional information about attendance boundaries and school activities.","HasHOA":true,"HOA":"","HOAFee":0,"HOABillingPeriod":"","CommissionPaid":"TBD","BuyerIncentive":"Please call for current incentives.","AgentIncentive":"Please call for current incentives.","PropertyImageID":5483435,"PropertyImage":"PropertyImages/20130218\\P1066637__021813220800_817965289_5483435.jpg","IsModified":false,"StatusID":40,"StatusDescription":"Active","EntryDate":new Date(1350438233950),"ModifyDate":new Date(1361225162697),"AvailableDate":new Date(-59011459200000),"UserIDModifiedBy":"4a2aef16-e7d9-469a-95ad-5c8935cb6bab","UserIDApprovedBy":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","UserIDCreatedBy":"4a2aef16-e7d9-469a-95ad-5c8935cb6bab","PropertyCountPerLogType":0,"PhotoSource":null,"CompletionDate":new Date(-59011459200000),"QAedFlag":null,"ProjectName":"","SitePlanSrc":null,"MarketingOverview":null,"AreaDescription":null,"DeveloperAndProjectTeam":null,"BuildingFeatures":null,"OtherInformation":null,"HOADocsPDF":null,"UnitNo":null,"ImageCount":0,"PropertyImageDescription":null,"ColorSchemeCode":null,"ColorSchemeId":0,"ColorSchemeName":null,"DirectionCode":null,"DirectionDescription":null,"ViewDescription":null,"BuilderEmail":null,"LogoSource":null,"CondoImageSource":"","FloorPlanCount":0,"MasterDescription":null,"ColorSchemeCount":0}]
```

but when pasring I am getting the exception

```
 org.json.JSONException: unterminated string at character 1919
```

That is when parsing this line

```
LotDescription":"David Weekley homes Traditional Collection in Baxter Village offers floor plans featuring innovative design and unsurpassed quality. This charming community combines work, play and living, all within the Village. In Baxter Village,
```

There is some special character in this word

```
 you&rsquo;ll
```

So, I am trying to replace double quote(") with escape double quote(\") and the code is ,

```
  public void ......(){
  httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
  HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
  String jsonstring=getJSONString(response);                
  JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonstring);
 }
  public String getJSONString(HttpResponse response) {

    try {
         DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
         Document doc = builder.parse(response.getEntity().getContent());
         NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("string");
         Node n = nl.item(0);
         String str = n.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().replace("\"", "\\\"");

         System.out.println("Node value : " +  str);
         return str;
          }catch(Exception e){}
     }
```

I am using replace function and replacing the string with escape quote thinking that the special characters will be parsed. but this doesn't seem to work.

I want the whole string in the format \"string\" or the whole string to be parsed. I did all the trails and did some research but could not find any solution.

Any ideas or suggestions please!! Thanks in advance!!!

the logcat is,

```
05-21 15:23:37.843: W/System.err(17883): org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at character 1919 of [{"TbbId":0,"PropertyID":1066637,"BuilderID":"9250c666-e76c-4206-8b37-343b2bb11a89","BuilderName":"David Weekley Homes","Notes":"","Address":"1 TBB4519","SchoolDistrict":null,"School":null,"CityID":"Fort Mill","CountyID":"","StateID":"SC","Zip":"29708","Lat":"35.037240000000000","Lng":"-80.979742000000000","Price":364990,"PropertyStatusID":"AV","PropertyStatusDescription":"Available","StageID":"TBB","StageDescription":"To-Be-Built Home","TypeID":1,"TypeDescription":"House","SubdivisionID":4121,"SubdivisionName":"Baxter Village","FloorPlanNumber":"4519","Remarks":"","OldNew":null,"PropertyInMyListFlag":null,"FreePostingFlag":"F","PropertySubscriptionPlan":null,"PropertySubscriptionPaymentType":null,"BalanceAmount":0,"PropertyLicenseFlag":"N","PlanNumber":null,"SubdivisionFloorPlanID":null,"SubdivisionFloorPlanName":"Ridgegate","ShowDirections":"Mon-Sat 9:30am-5:30pm; Sun 12:30pm-5:30","DrivingDirections":"Take I-77, Exit 85 - Fort Mill / Highway 160. Take Highway 160 West. Proceed past the Main Baxter Village Entrance. Turn Left into Baxter Village at the next entrance marked by a white fence and stone monument which is Front Street.  Take your first right onto Richards Crossing, the David Weekley Model is located on the left at 3439 Richards Crossi","PropertyClass":"TBB","RemarksId":0,"VerifiedBU":"Y","SubdivisionDescription":null,"Contact1Name":"Traci Belk","Contact1Phone":"800-393-9968","Contact1PhoneAlt":"","Contact2Name":"","Contact2Phone":"","Contact2PhoneAlt":"","Email":"homes@dwhomes.com","Beds":4,"Baths":2,"HalfBaths":1,"Living":0,"Dining":0,"OtherRooms":"","Stories":2.0,"Master":"Down","Garage":2.0,"SquareFeet":2474,"LotSize":"","LotDescription":"David Weekley homes Traditional Collection in Baxter Village offers floor plans featuring innovative design and unsurpassed quality. This charming community combines work, play and living, all within the Village. In Baxter Village, you
05-21 15:23:37.867: W/System.err(17883):    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:446)
05-21 15:23:37.867: W/System.err(17883):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextString(JSONTokener.java:226)
05-21 15:23:37.867: W/System.err(17883):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:103)
05-21 15:23:37.882: W/System.err(17883):    at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:381)
05-21 15:23:37.890: W/System.err(17883):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:96)
05-21 15:23:37.898: W/System.err(17883):    at org.json.JSONTokener.readArray(JSONTokener.java:426)
05-21 15:23:37.898: W/System.err(17883):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:99)
05-21 15:23:37.906: W/System.err(17883):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)
05-21 15:23:37.914: W/System.err(17883):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
```

And this is the getJSONString result,

```
 05-21 15:21:18.382: I/System.out(17883): Node value : [{"TbbId":0,"PropertyID":1066637,"BuilderID":"9250c666-e76c-4206-8b37-343b2bb11a89","BuilderName":"David Weekley Homes","Notes":"","Address":"1 TBB4519","SchoolDistrict":null,"School":null,"CityID":"Fort Mill","CountyID":"","StateID":"SC","Zip":"29708","Lat":"35.037240000000000","Lng":"-80.979742000000000","Price":364990,"PropertyStatusID":"AV","PropertyStatusDescription":"Available","StageID":"TBB","StageDescription":"To-Be-Built Home","TypeID":1,"TypeDescription":"House","SubdivisionID":4121,"SubdivisionName":"Baxter Village","FloorPlanNumber":"4519","Remarks":"","OldNew":null,"PropertyInMyListFlag":null,"FreePostingFlag":"F","PropertySubscriptionPlan":null,"PropertySubscriptionPaymentType":null,"BalanceAmount":0,"PropertyLicenseFlag":"N","PlanNumber":null,"SubdivisionFloorPlanID":null,"SubdivisionFloorPlanName":"Ridgegate","ShowDirections":"Mon-Sat 9:30am-5:30pm; Sun 12:30pm-5:30","DrivingDirections":"Take I-77, Exit 85 - Fort Mill / Highway 160. Take Highway 160 West. Proceed past the Main Baxter Village Entrance. Turn Left into Baxter Village at the next entrance marked by a white fence and stone monument which is Front Street.  Take your first right onto Richards Crossing, the David Weekley Model is located on the left at 3439 Richards Crossi","PropertyClass":"TBB","RemarksId":0,"VerifiedBU":"Y","SubdivisionDescription":null,"Contact1Name":"Traci Belk","Contact1Phone":"800-393-9968","Contact1PhoneAlt":"","Contact2Name":"","Contact2Phone":"","Contact2PhoneAlt":"","Email":"homes@dwhomes.com","Beds":4,"Baths":2,"HalfBaths":1,"Living":0,"Dining":0,"OtherRooms":"","Stories":2.0,"Master":"Down","Garage":2.0,"SquareFeet":2474,"LotSize":"","LotDescription":"David Weekley homes Traditional Collection in Baxter Village offers floor plans featuring innovative design and unsurpassed quality. This charming community combines work, play and living, all within the Village. In Baxter Village, you
```

Comment: also, post full stacktrace and put logs when you catch exception

Comment: @njzk, please find the above pasted logcat!!

Comment: your stacktrace is incomplete. it is supposed to indicate where in your code the issue precisely is. also, post getJSONString (as you can see in the result you posted, it is incomplete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace string before `Document doc = builder.parse();` because & is take as a illegal character.

So, you need to replace this character  before parse call.

```
      HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
    String xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
            (xml.replace("&", "&amp;"))
                    .getBytes("UTF-8"));
     Document doc = builder.parse(stream);
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Abdul, response is of type HttpResponse and not a string.Replace() do  work for only strings right.  I had already checked with that..

Comment: Thanks!! you could not assign a http content to a string variable. This wont work..

Comment: Sorry , i do not look it that you do not convert httpresponse to InputStream .

Comment: Thanks!! String has been replaced as "you&amp;rsquo;ll enjoy:&amp;nbsp; " but still it is not parceable!! Any Idea!!

Comment: you JSON is not valid here ,  "CompletionDate": newDate(-59011459200000), , please check JSON Valid or not.